# Unable to get the current url using jquery in Django developement server

Tags: jquery, django, url

I am using this to get the current url using jquery `var current_link = location).attr('href');` but when I try to display this link, just for debugging by

```
var current_link = $(location).attr('href');
    alert(current_link);
```

I get an alert of undefined. If I use this script in JSFiddle, I am getting the correct link. Is it s a problem of the django development server or by my browser or something else. Seems to be very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just do `location.href` ?

You don't need jQuery to get the current url.

```
var current_link = location.href
alert(current_link);
```

This has nothing to do with django :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution it is working fine now but I do not understand why the previous wasn't working

Answer (score 1):

When you get undefined for something you thing should exist I suggest you back-track until you find a valid value for something. You tried:

```
alert(current_link);
```

So the next step would be:

```
console.log(location);
```

to see what properties you can access on this object.

Note: To get the full current URL you can use `location.href`.

Here is documentation for the `window.location` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: just using location.href has worked but I fail to understand why

Comment: @Sachin Because `.attr()` is used to find attributes for DOM elements and `href` is an object property of the `location` object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Jasper, actually I had seen this method to extract the url on some post in stackoverflow only, so I was doing it that way